# LINQ Entity Data Reader does not support enums

Tags: entity-framework, enums, sqlbulkcopy

I have to do a batch insert of a lot of entities, so I figured the best way to do that was to use the [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class. However, that class operates on `DataReader` instances, whereas my code works with an IEnumerable where T is my entity class. To convert my IEnumerable to a DataReader, I found the following code: [LINQ Entity Data Reader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader).

This code works fine, but there is one problem: enum properties on my entity type are not included in the datareader (and therefore not being inserted correctly). How can I have the enum type properties be recognized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out this is due to the `IsScalarType` method not taking into account enums. This can easily be fixed by modifying the `IsScalarType` method as follows:

```
private static bool IsScalarType(Type t)
{
    // The || t.IsEnum part is new and makes sure that enums are recognized
    return scalarTypes.Contains(t) || t.IsEnum;
}
```

After this modification enum type will also be recognized.

Comment: Why not just replace all instances of `IsScalarType` with `t.IsValueType` where `t` is the type to check?

Comment: Structs are value types. Structs != scalar.

Comment: That's good, but not quite enough as it won't acknowledge nullable enum types as scalar types. I did some code to address that but somehow it still fails when bulk inserting. I'm still investigating.